# How to monitor conflicts at serial/CPU level between usb sensors, serial transmission and UDP streaming

Tags: ubuntu, usb, tty, serial-port, irq

I have a ARM64 [board](https://wiki.radxa.com/Rockpi4) running Ubuntu 18. The board runs a Python script that does the following:

- acquire data from a USB camera and a USB microphone
- process the data and send the result to an external controller via serial line (ttyS4), with a certain frequency (~10 Hz). According to `dmesg`, ttyS4 uses the interrupt mode as it fails to request DMA
- receive data from the same serial line
- stream and receive some information by sending and receiving UDP packets to/from a specific IP address

The acquisition, processing and transmission run in parallel on different processes. I want to make sure that there are no conflicts, in particular between the USB acquisition and the transmission on ttyS4. However I have no experience at this level and I don't know what tools should I use to monitor IRQs, DMA etc. and to fix my script accordingly. What are the best practices to follow in this case?